# cURL C Tutorial

Tags: c, gcc, curl

Does anyone know the relevant packages that need installing on Debian to enable me to use the curl libraries in my C app and does anyone have any decent links to tutorials about using curl in C.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two dev packages for libcurl. One that uses GnuTLS and another one that uses OpenSSL for encryption. I prefer the OpenSSL version (libcurl4-openssl-dev), because the default version of the libcurl library also uses OpenSSL.

You can find an extensive tutorial at the project's website: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html
The example source codes (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) are also worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

`libcurl3` seems to be a promising package for this purpose :) This of course assumes you want to use LibcURL rather than calling the curl shell program from within your program.